# I'd like to ask a question about the lowest prices per TB storage service. Is this maybe something superuser should allow?

Tags: discussion

I know very subjective questions aren't allowed. And especially this rule says I shouldn't ask such questions here:

> [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)
>
> ...
>
> and it is not about …
>
> - asking for a product, service or learning material recommendation,

I'm bringing it up here in meta because $/TB cloud storage seems like such an objective metric. It's almost a commodity now, and I'm sure we all could compile a great list which could be of great use.

I'd just like to hear your thoughts about it. Maybe it is something which should be allowed? An argument against, which comes to mind, is that it's a dynamic thing. It will change over time, and any answers will quickly become outdated.

Where else would such questions be suitable? My first thought is Reddit, or something like that, but I find stack exchange answers to be much better and of higher quality. I suppose [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) might be the right place, it's just that it seems to have such a low level of activity.

As it stands I'm not going to post the question here due to the rule mentioned above, but would like to hear your thoughts on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't do product recommendations because:

- The questions are not likely to help many people because specific use cases differ from person to person.
- The questions don't age very well, since software, prices, technology,  hardware... Everything is constantly evolving.

  > Where else would such questions be suitable? My first thought is Reddit, or something like that, but I find stack exchange answers to be much better and of higher quality. I suppose Software Recommendations might be the right place, it's just that it seems to have such a low level of activity.

Yes, you are much more likely to get specific answers on reddit in this case, since old reddit pages and posts get archived over time, and you could always ask the same question again.

That's not the case for SE posts and pages. These are literally *forever*. Something once asked cannot be asked again. As such, if we allowed questions with answers which keep changing over time, they would keep getting outdated and someone would have to edit them with up-to-date content. That's just not viable.

[softwarerecs.se](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) may not be as active as SU, but it is out of beta and is a proper SE site, so you can definitely expect decent answers. I suggest that you ask there if your questions fits within the scope of the site.

Other SE sites which may be of interest:

- [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)
- [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)

Reddit communities related to cloud storage:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/cloudstorage/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Cloud/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Archiveteam/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tend to agree with your points. I've invested some time over at SO, and your sentiment seems transferable. I [posted](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/45667/cheaper-tb-cloud-storage-alternatives-to-hetzners-storage-box-or-amazon-c) over at softwarerecs. From what I understand it seems to have the right fit there. If that fails, I'll bite the bullet and take it to reddit.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't a good fit over at softwarerecs either. I'll turn to the more casual sites/subreddits. Thanks again.

Comment: @AndréChristofferAndersen best of luck :)